# How can you return everything after last slash(/) in a Ruby string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a string would like everything after the last `/` to be returned.

E.g. for `https://www.example.org/hackerbob`, it should return `"hackerbob"`.

Comment: It would be much helpful if you could explain how to find "hackerbob" (e.g. give other examples of urls you need to parse), as is, you can just do `'https://www.facebook.com/hackerbob'[/hackerbob/]` But that's presumably not what you want. Are all your url's just Facebook usernames? What if it was like 'www.whatever.com/users/hackerbob' do you still want just hackerbob or 'users/hackerbob'? This question is too ambiguous.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek: From the title I'd say that OP wants to match the part of the URL after the last forward slash.

Comment: Should be everything after the last slash.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I don't think a regex is a good idea, seeing how simple the task is:

```
irb(main):001:0> s = 'https://www.facebook.com/hackerbob'
=> "https://www.facebook.com/hackerbob"
irb(main):002:0> s.split('/')[-1]
=> "hackerbob"
```

Of course you could also do it using regex, but it's a lot less readable:

```
irb(main):003:0> s[/([^\/]+)$/]
=> "hackerbob"
```

Comment: +1 for not using a hammer to drive screws.

Comment: thanks. the split idea is good too.

Comment: You could also use [String#rpartition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-rpartition)

Comment: In addition to being less readable, the regex method is also around 10 times slower that the split method, although it's only by about 0.01 seconds (`split:  0.001005s`, `regex: 0.010026s`). You should use split.

Comment: @Ekkstein what are you talking about

Comment: @Niklas B. Apologies, the problem was not your answer but part of my string. This answer works fine.

Answer (score 10):

Use the right tool for the job:

```
require 'uri'
url = "https://www.facebook.com/hackerbob"
URI.parse(url).path[1..-1]  # => "hackerbob"
```

Comment: I think this doesn't quite answer the question for URLs like `example.org/user/hackerbob` (which should result in `hackerbob`). To actually answer the question, we'd have to do `URI.parse(url).path.split('/')[-1]` or something, which then has no real advantage over just splitting the string in the first place

Answer (score 2):

One more sample

```
str = 'https://www.facebook.com/hackerbob'
ending = str.match(/.com\/(.*)/)
p ending[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can:

```
string = 'https://www.facebook.com/hackerbob'
string =~ /^https?:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/(.*)/
$1
```

Answer (score 0):

**May use this**

```
subject = /(\/)([^\/]+)\Z/i.match(subject)
if match
    # match start: match.begin(0)
    # match end (exclusive): match.end(0)
    # matched text: match[0]
    # backreference n start: match.begin(n)
    # backreference n end (exclusive): match.end(n)
    # backreference n text: match[n]
else
    # Match attempt failed
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use It

```
 1.9.3p194 :039 > line = 'https://www.facebook.com/hackerbob'
 1.9.3p194 :039 > line.match(/.com\/(\w+$)/)[1]  #    => "hackerbob"
```

Comment: The `.com\/` part of the regex is unnecessary... `/(\w+$)/` should be sufficient.

Comment: this doesn't work if the username is 'hacker.bob.9'

Answer (score 0):

You can try /[a-zA-Z]+://[a-z]+.[a-z]+.[a-z]+/(.+)/ if you are using it for the string above or any other similar url. A great tool to use for regex is http://www.rubular.com