# How to access to the company name into an email in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently trying to use the company name present into an email. But I don't find a simple way to access to. And ask i there is others.

An example is better than explanation :

User.new (mail) => user@company1.com

---

--> That the value that I want to catch <--

==> @company = company1

---

```
if Company.where(name: @company).any?
  render show @company 
else 
  reder new Company
end
```

So if you have any solutions to access to that, you'll be my hero !
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert on rails, but you can try this :

```
@pars1 = @company.split('@')
@pars2 = @pars[1].split('.')
@pars3 = @pars[0]
=> company
```

Try to read that, it can be useful :

> [How can you return everything after last slash(/) in a Ruby string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081504/how-can-you-return-everything-after-last-slash-in-a-ruby-string)

Comment: Thank dude, it will be really helpful